# NG0304: 'mat-select' is not a known element (used in the 'LoginPage' component template):

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, angular14

I just created a basic app and am trying to use Angular Material. This is an Ionic 6 / Angular 14 app. I'm getting the error below when trying to use mat-select:

[image]

I have added it to the imports in my app.module here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSelectModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my typescript looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';


@Component({
  imports: [
    MatSelectModule],
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  locations: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.locations = [
      {
        "DatabaseName": "TEST1"

      },
      {
        "DatabaseName": "TEST2"

      },
      {
        "DatabaseName": "TEST3"

      }
    ]

  }

}
```

and the HTML looks like:

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-col size="3"></ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">  
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location.DatabaseName">
                {{location.DatabaseName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3"></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

But I get the error in the screenshot above and my app looks like this:

[image]

Am I missing something simple? I thought it was as simple as adding it to the app.module and then using it throughout the app.

Comment: Did yu have another module where thé loginPage are declared? If not yu have to add LoginPage in the declaration array in yur app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Did yu have another module where the loginPage are declared?

If yes you have to import MatSelectModule in that module

If not yu have to add LoginPage in the declaration array in yur app.module.ts
Like this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginPage, AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSelectModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I don't think I have another module... It's basically the blank start ionic/angular app that I added another page to. I'll give this a shot and see if that's what I'm missing. Thanks

Comment: I tried that and now am getting the following error:   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type LoginPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and LoginPageModule! Please consider moving LoginPage to a higher module that imports AppModule and LoginPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoginPage then import that NgModule in AppModule and LoginPageModule.

Comment: So I removed the declaration from login.module and that fixed the issues. It looks like all is working correctly now. I guess my question would be is what did I just change moving the declaration of that page from the login.module --> app.module?